# Replicate the existing environment into a new VM

Tags: linux, rhel, kvm

We have a VM running in a box and that is the production server,the OS and release details are as follows.

```
en.ea $ uname -a
Linux en.ea.com 2.6.9-89.0.9.ELsmp #1 SMP Wed Aug 19 08:06:10 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
en.ea $ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 5)
```

The above box has got Weblogic 9.2,Oracle 10g and other applications installed and running live production data.

I need to replicate the current VM with all the current packages installed and with the applications into a new VM. That should be done in order to create a test environment.

Could anyone please recommend me the steps or any link that can be followed to do the above mentioned task. Is it feasible to replicate and do what i want to?

Comment: How about cloning the VM? Which is basically copying the disk image. You may have to change the IP address if it's configured to be static, but the rest should work as-is.

Comment: Are these hand crafted virts, or are you using some sort of configuration management?

Comment: @thrig We had a document of hardware and software requirements that should be relied on when building the server. But we lost it and would like to clone the existing built with all the currently installed and running applications, with directory structure and everyhting to be replicated into a new VM. Is it feasible? If so could you please share any documents that needs to be followed?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Okay, If you are sure all the applications running in the current environment would be going live in the newly cloned VM, Could you please share any documents that needs to be followed to acheive the result?

Comment: Given that by definition a clone is an exact copy, what is it about your situation that makes you think an identical copy would not work?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I am a total noob to this. I understood now. But you have documentation or steps on how to clone the VM?

Comment: Are you using plain KVM/QEMU, or libvirt?